# add-apt-repository fails during docker build

Tags: docker, apt, docker-build

I am trying to get the [dordoka/tomcat](https://hub.docker.com/r/dordoka/tomcat/) docker image up and running, but  I get this error when running `docker build`:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:~webupd8team/ubuntu/y-ppa-manager'.
ERROR: '~webupd8team' user or team does not exist.
The command '/bin/sh -c apt-get update && 
apt-get install -y software-properties-common &&
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/y-ppa-manager &&
add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/ubuntu/y-ppa-manager &&
apt-get update &&
apt-get install -y git build-essential curl wget software-properties-common'
returned a non-zero code: 1
```

The command that is failing is `add-apt-repository -y ppa:webupd8team/ubuntu/y-ppa-manager`. This command runs fine outside of docker. The proxy is configured correctly, as far as I can tell. Any ideas?

Comment: I havn't problem, try to delete this command from your dockerfile, RUN the image, and run the command inside the container.
docker exec -it [container-name] /bin/bash

Comment: I followed your advice, @Kilian, and narrowed the problem down to the proxy. I cannot even load an external web page using `curl`, so it’s no surprise that `add-apt-repository` doesn’t work. Now at least I know how to proceed.

Comment: The problem was that the proxy requires authentication, but root does not get Kerberos credentials. I added my user name and password to HTTPS_PROXY in the Dockerfile:
`ENV HTTPS_PROXY https://DOMAIN\USERNAME:PASSWORD@SERVER:PORT/`
After I made this change, the build worked fine.
Is there a way run as root, authenticate as another user, and still avoid using a hard-coded username and password?

Comment: You can create environment variables in your dockerfile, and register your user/pass with --env when you run your image. Not sure about your needs. (sry for my english)

Answer (score 1):

@mlowry Is there a particular reason why you have to run this as root?

I assume that when you run it as your user you have also the http_proxy exported ?

In this case you could youse --build-args to pass the http_proxy string.

Quick example:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-10-207:~/test$ docker build --build-arg http_proxy=$http_proxy .
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/4 : FROM alpine:latest
 ---> e21c333399e0
Step 2/4 : ARG http_proxy
 ---> Running in fd0832692097
Removing intermediate container fd0832692097
 ---> 4c58ddefe37c
Step 3/4 : RUN export HTTP_PROXY=$http_proxy
 ---> Running in 913dc802ea8f
Removing intermediate container 913dc802ea8f
 ---> 9c3280343c13
Step 4/4 : RUN env
 ---> Running in 0d078193475a
HOSTNAME=0d078193475a
SHLVL=1
HOME=/root
http_proxy=http://domain\user:pass@proxy.com:8080
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
PWD=/
Removing intermediate container 0d078193475a
 ---> d4b8996fbb09
Successfully built d4b8996fbb09
```